# Color Management and screen standby

Tags: color-management, display-calibration, windows

I've calibrated my notebook-Display using a Spyder3 pro.
The strange thing: when the notebook display goes blank for video standby and I wake it up by pressing a key or moving the mouse, for a second or two everything still looks calibrated, then the display has a short flicker and changes into uncalibrated display.

After some long seconds the DataColor software kicks in and applies the calibration again.

I don't want to switch off standby on my notebook - is there any other way to prevent windows from kicking out the calibration after standby? Why does windows disable it anyway??

Comment: it might not be Windows that is doing this, but your display driver. Is it nVidia?

Comment: This isn't behaviour I've seen, although I calibrate using an eyeOne device...

Comment: The GA device is an onboard intel 4500MHD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you go into standby mode, the amount of power draw is very low, just enough to keep things in RAM. Anything else is shut off to eliminate power consumption and that may include your video card if it supports it (and it most likely does). So, what I think is happening is that when you wake the machine, the initial display is effectively what was in the video buffer at time of sleep, the device driver then kicks in and resets the display, then, finally, the calibration software kicks in and recalibrates the display.

I see the same effect on my machine, so it's not specific to the Spyder3 as I use the Pantone Huey Pro. So, I think it's the video, it's effectively been shut off, and so it's largely the same effect as when you reboot.

Comment: I think John's got it. ICM increases resource usage, and it seems very logical that power-saving modes of a lap top would disable extraneous services when they are not needed. I don't think it is the DataColor software that is "kicking in", its more likely windows itself.